# Issue with UITextView cursor/scroll movement

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have used UITextView for chat like screenshot attached here.
[image]

But the problem is that If I press on return key of Keyboard, the cursor does not stick to bottom of UITextView bounds. Also I have used following code:

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if([textView contentSize].height <80.0)
    {
        CGFloat textHeight         = [self textHeightForTextView:textView];

        CGFloat newViewHeight = MAX(MIN(textHeight, 80.0), 33.0);

        chatTxtHeightConstraint.constant = newViewHeight;

        [textView scrollRangeToVisible:textView.selectedRange];
    }
}
```

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved issue by writing `[textView layoutIfNeeded];` and `[textView updateConstraints];` bellow code line of `chatTxtHeightConstraint.constant = newViewHeight;`

```
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if([textView contentSize].height <80.0)
    {
        CGFloat textHeight         = [self textHeightForTextView:textView];

        CGFloat newViewHeight = MAX(MIN(textHeight, 80.0), 33.0);

        chatTxtHeightConstraint.constant = newViewHeight;

        [textView layoutIfNeeded];
        [textView updateConstraints];

        [textView scrollRangeToVisible:textView.selectedRange];
    }
}
```